# поиск по дереву

Tags: javascript, дерево

Здравствуйте у меня есть дерево в таком виде

```
[
    {
        "name": "InvolvementType",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "FULL_TIME",
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "name": "PARTIAL",
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "name": "EPISODIC",
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "IncomeStatus",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "BILLABLE",
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "name": "NOT_BILLABLE",
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "technology",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Android",
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "name": "IOS",
                "children":[
                   {
    name: 'Objective C',
    children: null
    },
    {
    name: 'Swift',
    children: null
    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

мне нужно выбрав "swift" понимать что этот элимент дерева относится именно к "technology" а не к "InvolvementType". Как сделать поиск по дереву?

Comment: а что надо искать-то?

Comment: нужно найти именно родителя над которим уже нет родительского елемента т.е. для елемента у которого name: 'Swift' родителя именно technology, а не IOS

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. 
Я сделал функцию `findByName`, которая рекурсивно обрабатывает массив, и возвращает массив вида `["technology", "IOS", "Swift"]` который хранит путь он родителя до нужного элемента,

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "InvolvementType",
    "children": [{
        "name": "FULL_TIME",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "PARTIAL",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "EPISODIC",
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "IncomeStatus",
    "children": [{
        "name": "BILLABLE",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "NOT_BILLABLE",
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "technology",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Android",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "IOS",
        "children": [{
            name: 'Objective C',
            children: null
          },
          {
            name: 'Swift',
            children: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const findByName = (array, name, tail = []) => {
  for (const obj of array) {
    if (obj.name === name) {
      tail.push(obj.name);
      return tail;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
      const childrenTail = findByName(obj.children, name, [...tail].concat(obj.name));
      if (childrenTail.length) return childrenTail;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(findByName(array, 'EPISODIC'));
console.log(findByName(array, 'Swift'));
console.log(findByName(array, ''));
```

Comment: спасибо я приблизительно ето и имела ввиду

Comment: @Анна, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Qwertiy а если будет вложеность больше? и например гдето будет повторяться какието елементы например ветвь дерева с названием "Swift" может бить частью ветви "technology" и еще какойто ветви и нужно понимать   с какой именно ветви мы взяли веть "Swift"

Comment: @Анна, тут вроде весь путь выводится.

Comment: @Qwertiy если я добавлю ветвь 
{
            name: 'Swift',
            children: null
          } 
в ветвь 
{
    "name": "IncomeStatus",
    "children": [{
        "name": "BILLABLE",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "NOT_BILLABLE",
        "children": null
      },
{
            name: 'Swift',
            children: null
          }
 
    ]
  },

например так оно будет искать только первий варіант, а как найти второй варіант?

Comment: @Анна напишите пример результата, который вы хотите получить, а я подумаю